# Не получается запарсить xml

Tags: python

Прочитал документацию на сайте Питона о том, как и чем парсить XML. Взял XML:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.aviasales.ru/routes/kgs</loc>
        <lastmod>2018-06-01T00:00:00+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    ...
```

Пытаюсь получить нужные мне данные, но ничего не получается:

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for child in root.findall('loc'):
    urls.append(child.text)
```

Решил проверить, на каком этапе я ошибся и сделал просто:

```
print(root.findall('url'))
```

И получил в вывод пустой массив. Проверил, приходит ли xml - приходит. Так в чём же проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Это XML-пространства имен, увы. Ну и выражение поиска не совсем правильное. Для единственного применения пишем так:

```
root.findall('*/{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc')
```

Ну, если искать много раз, то заводим словарик и используем его:

```
ns = {'z': 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'}    
root.findall('*/z:loc', ns)
```

В  модуле lxml.etree можно написать для словарика

```
ns = {'z': root.nsmap[None]}
```

Если используются другие пространства, а не по умолчанию, то в lxml.etree просто используется значение `nsmap` и те же префиксы, что в исходном XML.

Answer (score -1):

```
import bs4
xml = """
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
     <url>
         <loc>https://www.aviasales.ru/routes/kgs</loc>
         <lastmod>2018-06-01T00:00:00+00:00</lastmod>
         <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
         <priority>0.5</priority>
     </url>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
soup.find_all('url')
```